# Import process fails : "Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found"

Tags: jss

I have Sitecore 9.0 update -1 version and followed (https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install) to setup JSS server.

I cant able to deploy the app while running deploy  command, i got below error in attached screen shot.

[image]

Below my scjssconfig.json

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "D:\\SC9\\sc90.local",
    "apiKey": "{781AA908-F82E-4122-87E7-AB4D60B76760}",
    "deploySecret": "eugskd8mophj3sq861yqybtttf3p5yctzxlu6rgk7m",
    "deployUrl": "http://sc90.local/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "http://sc90.local",
    "deploymentSecret":"eugskd8mophj3sq861yqybtttf3p5yctzxlu6rgk7m"
  }
}
```

Also i can see manifest.zip file in my local but seems import process fails.

How should i troubleshoot further here,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading jss server package solved my issues.

Based on this article "https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/09/02/troubleshooting-with-sitecore-jss-deployment-problems/"

My Jss-cli version(11.0) and react application versions are latest but my Jss server tech preview version is 2. So i downloaded tech preview version 4 and installed.

[image]

Now its worked.

[image]