# Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found

Tags: jss

Fresh new Sitecore XP 9.2 + JSS 12.0 and trying to deploy an OOTB react JSS app.

The ApiKey is created (with two `*` for test only).

The Layout Service is responding on `/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={...}` properly with `{"sitecore":{"context":{"pageEditing":false,"site":{"name":"website"}...`.

`jss setup` and `jss deploy config` worked perfectly.

When I run `jss deploy app -c -d` I have this error:

```
JSS is manifest packaging my-jss-app to ./sitecore/package...
Adding data/media/files/jss.pdf
Adding data/media/img/jss_logo.png
Adding data/media/img/sc_logo.png
Adding sitecore-import.json
Wrote sitecore\package\my-jss-app.1566916961828.manifest.zip
Sending package sitecore\package\my-jss-app.1566916961828.manifest.zip to http://jss-sc920-2.sc/sitecore/api/import...
Unexpected response from import service:
Status message: Found
Body: <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=%2fsitecore%2fapi%2fimport&amp;user=extranet%5cAnonymous&amp;site=website">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Really would appreciate any help.

**Note**: I'm already using all latest version so [Import process fails : "Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16270/import-process-fails-unexpected-response-from-import-service-status-message) doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4):

I had also faced similar situation , in my case following 3 points needed to be changed :

1) Make sure your Sitecore License has JSS license included , you can check this from licenses

[image]
[image]

2) Make sure you have installed the JSS Server Components Sitecore package through installation wizard as per your Sitecore instance version from following link.
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services.aspx

3) Make sure that when JSS setup command is executed and you are prompted to provide option , provide the app name of your jss app in Sitecore hostname , similarly Sitecore Service URL as shown below. Of course new IIS site binding and host entry is also required.
Also make sure no VPN or proxy is affecting your copying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I just come across this issue, while i investigate then found my Import service url was wrong*

Import Service Url: **http://App_name/sitecore/api/jss/import**

File where configuration given for below config file:-
File Name: **scjssconfig**
Path: **D:\App_Name (Root Folder of App)**