# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element

Tags: jss, deployment, react

After I input the command with the certificate

```
jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary --acceptCertificate ww:ww:11:....
```

Following error shows up.I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2 and doing the deploy of a react app. I already installed jss package on the Sitecore instance. My Sitecore instance is located locally.

I followed every steps from the Sitecore documentation [here](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start).

[image: The error that shows me]

Comment: can you give more info about log errors and browser console errors ?

Comment: this is the console: https://imgur.com/a/Sn1zdbQ

Comment: plz chek whether your Layout Service is working correctly, in your case it will be 

sxa_app.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={YOUR_API_KEY_ID}

This question is possible duplicate of 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/unexpected-response-from-import-service-status-message-found

Comment: the layout service is working correctly because it returns the correct json when i type the link you provided. After seeing the other question you suggested i tried the solution of the answer but it seems all correct (we have the jss license installed). Is it possible that i might have to install an import service or something like that?

Comment: Do you have Sitecore Commerce installed on that particular instance?

Comment: yes i have sitecore commerce installed

Comment: What is the version of the JSS and Commerce you’ve installed?

Comment: I think the commerce versione is 11.2.83 and the jss version is 9.0 tech preview 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Sitecore Commerce is not yet compatible with Sitecore JSS as shown from the comparison tables.

**From Sitecore JSS Site**

URL: [JSS Release Note](https://jss.sitecore.com/release-notes)

Currently as I am answering, the version is Sitecore JSS 13.0 for Sitecore 9.3

[image]

**From Sitecore Experience Commerce**

URL: [Sitecore Experience Commerce compatibility](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/804595)

As we talk, there are no mention of the compatibility between Commerce and JSS in the Sitecore XP and Modules Compatibility Section.

However, you can use Sitecore Commerce but requires custom development. More information is available at the [Sitecore JSS Help](https://jss.sitecore.com/help) page.

[image]