# Sitecore JSS Import Service issue

Tags: sitecore-client, jss

- I have installed the plain `Sitecore 10.3 XP` in my local.
- Installed the `Sitecore headless rendering 21.0.1 package` from this URL https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering/21x/Sitecore_Headless_Rendering_2101.aspx
- Created the API key and verified the service `https://sc103-sc/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={03E4BE22-4625-4612-98B4-C735C5131B23}` it's worked.
- Followed the steps to setup the first JSS application in my local and after I tried to deploy the application to Sitecore path with the command `jss deploy app -- includeContent --includeDictionary`

It got failed and received the error in the command prompt as below :

[image]

**received the error in log file as below**

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: A public action method 'Import' was not found on controller 'Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.ImportService.Controllers.JssImportHostController'.
Source: System.Web.Mvc
```

**When I access the import URL in browser, receive the error as below**

[image]

From this thread [Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/unexpected-response-from-import-service-status-message-found), I found the below :

> Make sure you have installed the JSS Server Components Sitecore package through installation wizard as per your Sitecore instance version from following link. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services.aspx

Do I need to add the package "**Sitecore JavaScript Services 15.0.1**" also? from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/150/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_1501.aspx or installing the package "Sitecore headless rendering 21.0.1" is enough ?

I tried to install the **Sitecore JavaScript Services 15.0.1** on top of it. Installation got failed, earlier, I have been asked to overwrite few config files related to JSS. Finally my Sitecore instance got broken and throwing the following error now.

[image]

Can anyone help me for the JSS application development and deployment do i need both (**Sitecore Headless Rendering 21.0.1** and **Sitecore JavaScript Services 15.0.1**) the package installed in my vanilla Sitecore version ?

What could be the reason for failing with Import Service?

Comment: Which package from link you have installed? XP or XM one. Can you please update your question? You don;t need to install Sitecore Javascript Services 15, Headless Rendering is enough for Sitecore 10.3 as Javascript Services were renamed in Sitecore 10.1

Comment: What versions of npm jss packages do you use in your FE project? Can you please share your packages.json?

Comment: I have updated the question with my packages.json. I have sitecore 10.3 XP standalone sitecore + Sitecore Headless Rendering 21.0.1 (Sitecore Headless Services for Sitecore XP)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. When I create a JSS app, I was providing my Sitecore hostname, which caused redirecting round robin and throwing error. My understanding is, I can provide the Sitecore host name in one place where I am supposed to provide the Sitecore hostname.

Comment: Hello, I am having a similar issue. I am not clear on what host name i should provide. When it asks for sitecore host name, do I provide the host name to my sitecore instance?
Or the host name for the app I am creating?

Comment: Host name is your JSS app host name which you provide in host file and binding.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue during installation, after some investigation I found that I was using an incorrect entry for the Sitecore hostname. When I corrected it so that it mapped to the path to the Sitecore folder, that resolved this issue.

Hope this helps.