# JSS Deploy app -c -d failing with Status message : Bad Request

Tags: jss

**Analysis:** After searching on Stack Exchange, I did not find the solution. I went through [Import process fails : "Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16270/import-process-fails-unexpected-response-from-import-service-status-message) and [Unexpected response from import service: Status message: Found](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/unexpected-response-from-import-service-status-message-found/28571#28571) that were near my issue. But the solution provided there will not work in my situation.

**Problem:** I have installed JSS in disconnected mode, and it works perfectly fine. Now I was trying to install the Sitecore(10.1) JSS in connected mode.

[image]

My DNS provided in configuration is working as shown below:

[image]

But the import URL is giving a 404, as shown below:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is reactdemo.dev.local your react application or your CM?

Comment: 400 bad request. One of response could be absence or incorrect api key. 
Can you double check that your configuration was deployed? (Did you deploy it using `jss deploy config` command line?)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your responses, @Richard Seal and @Anton.

But, I was ultimately able to understand it after hours of effort. The answer is really quite easy. This step was not mentioned in any installation videos or blogs that I read. After using the `jss setup` command and completing the setup, the following information is returned.

[image]

It states,

1. Ensure Host name in few place.
2. Deploy your configuration.
3. Deploy your app.
4. Test your app.

I omitted step two (Deploy your configuration). I was therefore receiving an error.

I'm hoping that this will be useful to others.

Comment: hehe, so actually, I guessed!